# selection value is not reading in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, http, service

I have a form, after filling the data in it, I am send it to server through http post method in angularjs, the issue is, it is reading/getting all values except value in the select box, it is reading/getting as null value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>KunEra ERP</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Booststrap compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- customized stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css">
        
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">
        <jsp:include page="menubar.jsp" />
             
        <!-- Product Id Table -->
        <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="postserviceCtrl">
            
            <form ng-submit="postdata(proid, pname, pselect, pbrand, pcolor, pquanity, pprice, psize, pgst, pdealer, paddress)" name="myForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal center-block" id="product-table">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Product</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-id">Product ID:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" ng-model="proid" class="form-control" name="product-id" id="product-id" placeholder="Product ID" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{4,20}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-name">Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <input type="text" ng-model="pname" class="form-control" name="product-name" id="product-name" placeholder="Product Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,20}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-category">Category:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10" required>          
                      <select required class="form-control" name="product-category" id="product-category">
                        <option ng-model="pselect">Select</option>
                        <option ng-model="pselect">Shirts</option>
                        <option ng-model="pselect">Trousers</option>
                        <option ng-model="pselect">Jackets</option>
                        <option ng-model="pselect">T-Shirts</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-brand">Brand:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <input type="text" ng-model="pbrand" class="form-control" name="product-brand" id="product-brand" placeholder="Brand" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,20}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-color">Color:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <input type="text" ng-model="pcolor" class="form-control" name="product-color" id="product-color" placeholder="color" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,10}">
                  </div>
                </div>    
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-quanity">Quanity:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <input type="number" ng-model="pquanity" class="form-control" name="product-quanity" id="product-quanity" placeholder="Quanity" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-price">Price:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <input type="number" ng-model="pprice" class="form-control" name="product-price" id="product-price" placeholder="Price" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-size">Size:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <input type="number" ng-model="psize" class="form-control" name="product-size" id="product-size" placeholder="size" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-gst">GST:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <input type="number" ng-model="pgst" class="form-control" name="product-gst" id="product-gst" placeholder="GST" required >
                  </div>
                </div>
                    
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-dealer">Dealer Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <input type="text" ng-model="pdealer" class="form-control" name="product-dealer" id="product-dealer" placeholder="Dealer Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,20}">
                  </div>
                </div>    
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-address">Address:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                      <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="paddress" name="product-address" id="product-address" placeholder="Address" required minlength="20" maxlength="100">
                    </textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>        
                    
                <div class="form-group">        
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ADD</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">RESET</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </fieldset>    
            </form>
        </div>
      
        <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- customized javascript -->
        <script src="../js/javascript.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
            app.controller('postserviceCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.proid = null;
                $scope.pname = null;
                $scope.pselect = null;
                $scope.pbrand = null;
                $scope.pcolor = null;
                $scope.pquanity = null;
                $scope.pprice = null;
                $scope.psize = null;
                $scope.pgst = null;
                $scope.pdealer = null;
                $scope.paddress = null;
                $scope.postdata = function (proid, pname, pselect, pbrand, pcolor, pquanity, pprice, psize, pgst, pdealer, paddress) {
                    var data = {
                        proid: proid,
                        pname: pname,
                        pselect: pselect,
                        pbrand: pbrand,
                        pcolor: pcolor,
                        pquanity: pquanity,
                        pprice: pprice,
                        psize: psize,
                        pgst: pgst,
                        pdealer: pdealer,
                        paddress: paddress
                    };
//Call the services
                    $http.post('https://reqres.in/api/users', JSON.stringify(data)).then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data){
                            alert("success");
                        console.log(response);}
                    }, function (response) {
                        alert("error");
                    });
                };
            });
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried inserting  ng-mobel in select tag and removed in options but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` have to be added to the `select`, not to the `option`.

Additionaly I would suggest you to display `selects` **by using `ng-options` directive**:

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-options="item for item in selectValues" ng-model="pselect" required class="form-control" name="product-category" id="product-category"></select>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
$scope.selectValues = ["Shirts", "Trousers", "Jackets", "Tshirts"];
```